# Битрикс получение выбранного значения пользовательского поля типа список

Tags: php, битрикс

Есть пользовательськое поле (ID 46) c кодом showblockrend в Iblock ID 2 
Поле типа список, значение только одно - Да, не объязательное. по умолчанию не задано. внешний вид флажки. 
логика - если выделено то не показываем определенный блок. 
никак не могу получить чекнут ли флажок.
пробовал вот так проверять - ничего не дало

```
 function GetListValueById($ID)
{
   $UserField = CIBlockPropertyEnum::GetList(array(), array("ID" => $ID));
   if($UserFieldAr = $UserField->GetNext())
   {
      return $UserFieldAr["VALUE"];
   }
   else return false;
}   
echo GetListValueById(46);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для работы со свойствами типа список лучше всего использовать специально сделанный для них класс [`CIBlockPropertyEnum`](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA) (о чудо ссылка на него первая при запросе в гугл "[битрикс получить значение свойства типа список](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA)") и его метод [`GetList`](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/classes/ciblockpropertyenum/getlist.php)

Вот пример:

```
<?php
$property_enums = CIBlockPropertyEnum::GetList(Array(), Array("IBLOCK_ID"=>2, "PROPERTY_ID"=>46));
while($enum_fields = $property_enums->GetNext())
{
  echo $enum_fields["ID"]." - ".$enum_fields["VALUE"]."<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Спасибо! в битриксе пока не очень разбираюсь. и вот здесь https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/classes/ciblockelement/getproperty.php  искал вместо  CIBlockPropertyEnum